# How to get process, thread and logged user ID on Android with Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, java-native-interface, pid

I want to get the following, so I can write a proper log:

- Process ID
- Thread ID
- Logged on user ID (could be empty on older Android versions)

How can this be done with Delphi. Probably with JNI, but I have no clue where to start.

Comment: See if you can find anything useful inside `Androidapi.JNI.App.pas` in the `Source\RTL\Android` library (XE7).

Comment: I am still on XE6, but will migrate to XE7 shortly. I will check, thanks.

Comment: JNI will not help here because Delphi apps runs on the bare OS, not in a virtual machine

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but the question remains.

Comment: @mjn Why won't JNI help?

Comment: Hi, I'm looking for the same thing, I'm specifically looking for a substitute of windows GetCurrentProcessID. If you could share your findings I'd appreciate it. Thanks.